# VBScript Strange Issue with HTA and Type mismatch error

Tags: vbscript, hta, type-mismatch

When I run the following script on it's own by double clicking, it works just fine. It returns the last logged on user as expected. But when I run it from the HTA I have been developing as a front end to all of my scripts, I get a type mismatch error on the  "wscript.echo strvalue" line. I have tried everything to get it to work, like changing permissions on mshta.exe to full control for myself. I simply can't get it to run from the HTA without getting an error, but it works 100% as expected on its own. I am completely stumped.

```
strinput = "myserver"
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
strinput & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
 strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI"
strValueName = "LastLoggedOnUser"
 objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
 Wscript.Echo strValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Windows 64-bit uses `MSHTA.EXE` 32-bit. The registry has a separate branches for 64-bit and 32-bit apps, thus WMI can't find the registry value you are looking for.
Save the code below to e. g. `C:\test\tmp.hta`, try to launch it from explorer by double-click (32-bit by default) - you will get `null`, and then launch via Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) with path: `%windir%\system32\mshta.exe "C:\test\tmp.hta"` (64-bit), the result will be your username.

```xml
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="vbscript">
            Sub window_onload()
                Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002 
                Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
                strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI"
                strValueName = "LastLoggedOnUser"
                objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
                document.body.innerText = strValue
            End Sub
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that many other stuff within scripts depends on application architecture, e. g. number of ActiveX are available only in 32-bit version, so they should be launched via `%windir%\SysWOW64\` (Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit subsystem).

Comment: I forgot to include the constant in my original code. But it's already there. Again it works fine by double clicking, but through the HTA it returns an error. Why would it work with one method and not the other? Makes no sense at all.

Comment: That's what it was! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Msgbox` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(v=vs.84).aspx) instead of `Wscript.Echo` method. HTAs use the *Internet Explorer Scripting Object Model* which does not contain `Wscript` object (this belongs to [Windows Script Host Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a74hyyw0(v=vs.84).aspx)).

Read [HTA: Why Can’t I Use Wscript.Echo?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx#EGAA):

> You might have noticed that when it came time to report back the
>   operating system version we used the VBScript Msgbox function rather
>   than the more common Wscript.Echo. Why didn’t we use Wscript.Echo?
>   Here’s why:
>
> [image: Error Message]
>
> As it turns out the various Wscript methods - Wscript.Echo,
>   Wscript.Sleep, Wscript.Quit, etc. - are designed solely to run under
>   the Windows Script Host environment. When we’re working in an HTA
>   we’re not running under WSH; instead we’re running under the MSHTA
>   process. Because of that the Wscript methods are not available to us
>   (nor can we create them). Consequently we need to find workarounds for
>   each method, and Msgbox is a perfectly adequate replacement for
>   Wscript.Echo. (We’ll talk about workarounds for other methods - such
>   as Wscript.Sleep - when we get to them.)
>
> The moral of the story: Don’t bother with Wscript.Echo; it won’t work.

**Edit**: with `Wscript.Echo TypeName(strValue) & vbNewLine & VarType(strValue)`:

```
==> C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe D:\VB_scripts\SO\33505295.vbs
String
8

==> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe D:\VB_scripts\SO\33505295.vbs
Null
1
```

Tried in a simple `HTA` which gives the same (different) result

```
==> C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe 33505295.hta
```

versus

```
==> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe 33505295.hta
```

**Conclusion**. Check `HTA` file type association. For instance, `ftype htafile` in my Windows 8 (64bit) returns (surprisingly?) the same value which causes wrong behaviour on double click:

```
==> assoc .hta
.hta=htafile

==> ftype htafile
htafile=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe "%1" {1E460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5}%U{1E460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5} %*
```

Comment: Did not work. When I changed 'wscript.echo strvalue' to 'msgbox strvalue' I got a different Error: Invalid use of Null:strValue Code: 800A005E on the line that I changed. Again running the script by double clicking works fine. Running the script through the HTA returns that error.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same challenge a few weeks ago.
The following code provided me the possibility to see who is currently logged onto a remote computer.

I hope this can help you.

```
Sub ActionGetCurrentUser(strCPU) 'strCPU is the computername
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strCPU & "\root\cimv2")
    set Items = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each obj in Items
        OutStr = right(obj.username,9)
    Next

    Resultstring = "Logged in User is: " & OutStr   

    Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    strTarget = "LDAP://" & strDNSDomain
' ---------------- Write the User's account & password to a variable -------------------
    strCurrentuser = Currentuser.value
    strPassword = PasswordArea.value
' ---------------- Connect to Ad Provider ----------------
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Properties("User ID") = strCurrentUser     ' pass credentials - if you omit this, the search is performed....
    objConnection.Properties("Password") = strPassword       ' ... with the current credentials
    objConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True      ' only needed if you set "User ID" and "Password"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set objCmd =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection 

    objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DisplayName FROM '" & strTarget & "' WHERE extensionAttribute11 = '" & OutStr & "'"    

    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    objCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    objCmd.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    objCmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
    objCmd.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    Set objRecordSet = objCmd.Execute

    If objRecordset.Recordcount = 0 then    ' If no user is found then the recordcount will be 0
        msgbox "No user is logged on"
        Resultstring = ""
        Set objCmd = Nothing
        Set objRootDSE = Nothing
        Set objRecordSet = Nothing
        Set objWMI = Nothing
        Set Items = Nothing
        exit sub
    End if

    Set objRecordSet = objCmd.Execute

    objRecordSet.MoveFirst

    Resultstring = Resultstring & vbcrlf & "Name: " & objRecordset.fields("DisplayName")        

    Msgbox Resultstring

    Resultstring = ""

    Set objCmd = Nothing
    Set objRootDSE = Nothing
    Set objRecordSet = Nothing
    Set objWMI = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```